# How to develop an Import/Export Functionality for my node application

Tags: node.js, algorithm, import, architecture, export

I have a configuration application in Nodejs. It has a `Component` with `name` and `uuid`. A `Component` can have many `Schemas`. A `Schema` has a `uuid`, `name`, `componentId`, `json`. A `Schema` can have many `Configurations`. A `Configuration` has `name`, `schemaId`, `json` and `uuid`. A `Schema` can contain reference of many other `Schemas` in it. Now I want to create a functionality of exporting all the data from one instance of the application and import it in another. What should be the simplest way to do it? a few questions are

1. How to tell application what to export. for now i think there should be separate arrays for components, schemas and configurations. Like

```
{
    components: ['id1', 'id2'],
    schemas: ['s1', 's2'],
    configuration: ['c1', 'c2'],
}
```

this data should be sent to application to return a file with all information that will later be used for importing in another instance

1. The real question is how should my export file look like keeping in mind that dependencies are also involved and dependencies can also overlap. for example a schema can have many other schemas referenced in its json field. eg `schema1` has `schema2` and `schema4` as its dependencies. so there is another schema `schema5` that also require `schema2`. so while importing we have to make sure that `schema2` should be saved first before saving `schema1` and `schema5`. how to represent such file that requires order as well as overlapped dependencies, making sure that `schema2` is not saved twice while importing. `json` of `schema1` is shown below as an example

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "p1": {
        "$ref": "link-to-schema2"
    },
    "p2": {
        "$ref": "link-to-schema4"
    },

}
```

3. What should be the step wise sudo algorithm i should follow while importing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect occasion for a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

Taking away components, schemas and configurations terminology, what you have is objects (of various kinds) which depend on other objects existing first.  A topological sort will create an order that has only forward dependencies (assuming you don't have circular ones, in which case it is impossible).

But the complication is that you have dependency information in a mix of directions.  A component has to be created before its schema.  A schema has to be created after the schemas that it depends on.  It is not impossible that those schemas may belong to other components that have to be created as well.

The first step is to write a function that takes an object and returns a set of dependency relationships discoverable from the object itself.  So we want `dependencyRelations(object1` to give something like `[[object1, object2], [object3, object1], [object1, object4]]`.  Where `object1` depends on `object2` existing.  (Note, `object1` will be in each pair but can be first or second.)

If every object has a method named `uniqueName` that uniquely identifies it then we can write a method that works something like this (apologies, all code was typed here and not tested, there are probably syntax errors but the idea is right):

```
function dependencyInfo (startingObject) {
    const nameToObject = {};
    const dependencyOf = {};
    const todo = [startingObject];
    const visited = {};

    while (0 < todo.length) {
        let obj = todo.pop();
        let objName = obj.uniqueName();
        if (! visited[ objName ]) {
            visited[ objName ] = true;
            nameToObject[objName] = obj;
            dependencyRelations(obj).forEach((pair) => {
                const [from, to] = pair;
                // It is OK to put things in todo that are visited, we just don't process again.
                todo.push(from);
                todo.push(to);
                if (! dependencyOf[from.uniqueName()]) {
                    dependencyOf[from.uniqueName()] = {}
                }
                dependencyOf[from.uniqueName()] = to.uniqueName();
            });
        }
    }
    return [nameToObject, dependencyOf];
}
```

This function will construct the dependency graph.  But we still need to do a topological sort to get dependencies first.

```
function objectsInOrder (nameToObject, dependencyOf) {
    const answer = [];
    visited = {};

    // Trick for a recursive function local to my environment.
    let addObject = undefined;
    addObject = function (objName) {
        if (! visited[objName]) {
            visited[objName] = true; // Only process once.
            // Add dependencies
            Object.keys(dependencyOf[objName]).forEach(addObject);
            answer.push(nameToObject[objName]);
        }
    };
    Object.keys(dependencyOf).forEach(addObject);
    return answer;
}
```

And now we have an array of objects such that each depends on the previous ones only.  Send that, and at the other end you just inflate each object in turn.

Comment: can you explain `dependencyOf` especially `if (! dependencyOf[from.uniqueName()])`

Comment: also there can be standalone objects with no dependencies and there can also be 2 3 ... disconnected graphs also e.g `obj1` requires `obj2`, `obj3` and `obj4` requires `obj5`. `dependencyInfo(obj1)` will not cover `obj4`, `obj5`. there is a need of giving a whole array of schemas to `dependencyInfo` function to create a complete graph (covering all objects) to get sorted

Comment: If `bar` is a key in the `dependencyOf` for `foo`, then you have to build `bar` first.  And the reason for that if check is because I want it to be a hash of hashes, so if the subhash doesn't exist, I want to create it.  JavaScript might or might not create it for you (that is called autovivification) but I switch languages enough that I don't want to memorize the fact.